# Random samples for particular cov(X,X), and cov(X,X.^2)

Tags: probability, linear-algebra

I have an empirical sample of multivariate data and I want to generate surrogate data **X** that matches certain characterizations of my data:
cov(**X**,**X**) = **A**, and
cov(**X**,**X**.***X**) = **B**
where **X**.***X** is the Hadamard power of **X**.

I know I can use the Cholesky decomposition of **A** with normally distributed random values to construct a sample preserving only the covariance structure. Is there anything analogous I can do here?

Comment: In the univariate case there's procedures for generating samples matching second and third and (often) fourth moments. I am not aware of any for the multivariate case but I wouldn't be at all surprised to find them; chances are they're likely to be framed in terms of co-skewness

Comment: Thanks Glen. It's not clear to me how to relate expression involving the *element-wise* square of **X** to moments of **X**. Any thoughts?